# JQuery add a Div after checkbox list

Tags: jquery

How do I add a div after each item in a checkbox list. My new div should be right after the clicked Item and before the next item in the checkbox list control in asp.NET I know that the checkbox list is rendered as a table and each item is in a tr and an input and label inside the td

table
for each item
----table row
----td
-----input and label

end foreach
/table

I need to add a div after the label of the checked item in the checkboxlist using "jQuery". How do i find the label tag and insert the div from there on....?/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're inserting outside, so you'll want to use after.

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content

```
$("table label").after("<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo).

It sounds like you're using ASP.NET CheckBoxList.  So probably something like this would work (I haven't tested this):

```
$("table label").each(function() {
     $(this).appendTo("<div>your new div</div>");
});
```

Comment: I need to add a div but appendTO is removing the td and adding the new div?.